# Считывание до знака "метки "

Tags: c++, qt

Считываю текст  из файла wivod.txt.
В файле лежит :

```
13.34 *Длительность приема сигнала (м.с) 
48 *Коэффицент усиления (dB) 
1 *Заполнение импульса 
48000 *Частотный диапазон 
0.1 *Множитель амплитуды
```

Знак " * " что после него лежит пояснительный текст

Хочу считать до " * ", потом перейти на следующую стоку и забрать в массив переменную (число)  .

Вопрос : Как считать до текстовой метки " * "

Comment: А просто читать число, а потом убирать все до конца строки не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QFileDialog dlg(this);
QString D_path = "C:/WORK/";
QString D_format = "txt";
isRead = dlg.getOpenFileName(this,trUtf8("Открываем  условия запуска "),D_path,trUtf8("DUMP(*.%1)").arg(D_format));
qDebug()<< isRead;
qDebug()<< "мы тут загружаем";
// переводим в из QString в char
char* value_name = new char[255];
char* sometext=isRead.toAscii().data();
value_name = sometext;


char peremen_t[255]; // результат будем складывать сюда 

int t = 0; // счетчик peremen_t

QFile file(value_name);
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly |QIODevice::Text))
{
    while(!file.atEnd())
    {

        //читаем строку
        QString str = file.readLine();
        for (int i =0; i<str.size();++i)
        {

            if(str[i] == '*')
            {

                break; // если  str[i] == '*' то сбрасывает строку 

            }
            peremen_t[t] = str[i].toAscii();
            t= t+1;

        }
    }
}
else
{
    qDebug()<< "don't open file";
}
qDebug()<<"peremen_t " << peremen_t;
```

А вот и результат :  peremen_t  13.34 48 1 48000 0.1

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь [`QString::split`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split):

```
QStringList list = str.split("*");
if (list.isEmpty()) continue; 
double variable = list[0].toDouble();
```

Comment: QStringList list = str.split("*");    побывал ругается на него

Comment: @timob256 что значит ругается? Приведите код ошибки. Код, который я написал, проверенный и рабочий

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно проблема в пробеле после числа, в следствии чего возможна ошибка конвертации.

Answer (score 3):

```
QString str = "13.34 *Длительность приема сигнала (м.с) ";
str = str.mid(0, str.indexOf("*"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
template<class T>
struct Line{
    T value;
    std::string name;
};
template<class T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Line<T> &line){
    is >> line.value;
    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '*');
    is >> line.name;
    return is;
}

int main(){
    Line<double> line;
    std::cin >> line;
    std::cout << line.name << "  " << line.value;
}
```

В функции `main` я читаю значение из `std::cin`, но вы можете использовать любой поток ввода `std::sstream`, `std::fstream` или даже какую-нибудь собственную реализацию.

**UPD**. Если вдруг вам нужно только первое число, можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
template<class T>
T get(std::istream &is){
    T result;
    is >> result;
    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return result;
}

int main(){
    double d;
    d = get<double>(std::cin);
}
```

Функция `get` считывает первое значение, и пропускает строку до конца. Опять же, вместо `std::cin` можно использовать `std::sstream` или `std::fstream`